# sql substring advice

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, charindex, patindex

I need an advice with gettin substring from a long string like:
"/Q2-2020/ CompanyName, Some more additional details (12:20 - 15:37), Krakow"

What i need is get from this string the end time (later time from parentheses) in separate column

It can also happen that time is written the other way (in format to-from)

any ideas how can i figure this out?
Thanks

Comment: You have tagged your question with MySQL . . . and "patindex" and "charindex".  However, those are not MySQL functions.  Are you sure you are using MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MYSQL and bracketed times are the last bracketed items in the string

```
set @a = '/Q2-2020/ CompanyName, Some more additional details (12:20 - 15:37), Krakow';

select substring_index(@a,'(',-1),
         substring_index(substring_index(@a,'(',-1),')',1),
         replace(substring_index(substring_index(@a,'(',-1),')',1),' ',''),
         substring_index(replace(substring_index(substring_index(@a,'(',-1),')',1),' ',''),'-',-1)
```

I have left all the intermediate steps in to demonstrate how the final result is achieved,